# Apache Tez build failed because of tez-ui

Tags: apache, maven, tez

I cannot build Apache Tez with tez-release-0.7.0 because of failure on tez-ui.
This is my command in Ubuntu:

`mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dfrontend-maven-plugin.version=0.0.23`

Where should I fix it now?
Thank you guys a lot.

```
[INFO] tez ................................................ SUCCESS [  1.177 s]
[INFO] tez-api ............................................ SUCCESS [ 14.120 s]
[INFO] tez-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  2.484 s]
[INFO] tez-runtime-internals .............................. SUCCESS [  3.732 s]
[INFO] tez-runtime-library ................................ SUCCESS [  9.160 s]
[INFO] tez-mapreduce ...................................... SUCCESS [  5.508 s]
[INFO] tez-examples ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.173 s]
[INFO] tez-dag ............................................ SUCCESS [ 16.850 s]
[INFO] tez-tests .......................................... SUCCESS [  3.581 s]
[INFO] tez-ui ............................................. FAILURE [01:33 min]
[INFO] tez-plugins ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-yarn-timeline-history .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-yarn-timeline-history-with-acls ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-mbeans-resource-calculator ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-tools .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-dist ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Tez ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-28T23:31:25+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 64M/197M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16:npm (npm install) on project tez-ui: Failed to run task: 'npm install --color=false' failed. (error code 255) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :tez-ui
```

Comment: my protoc version: libprotoc 2.5.0. node -v --> v4.2.6. npm -v --> 3.5.2

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: I ran into the same problem which solved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51020318/8137610)

Answer (score 1):

Install git, node & npn. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in .bowerrc file present under tez-ui/src/main/webapp/ and build again

```
"registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed 'tez-ui' from the pom altogether, which may be an option depending on your situation