# EINVRES Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular failed with 502, I don't have .bowerrc

Tags: angularjs, heroku, bower

I'm updating my webapp hosted on heroku that is written in AngularJS and have no .bowerrc file but instead bower.json and package.json. I experience the same problem as in this thread: [EINVRES Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ failed with 502](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51020317)

However it does not work for me neither to add the registry line to `bower.json` or `package.json`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Update your version of bower. Run:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

I assume you had been trying to run `bower install`. This update solved the problem for me.